# Swift equivalent of string literal interfaces? - `request(method: 'post'|'put')`

Tags: swift, function, types, swift4, swift-protocols

In TypeScript I can do things like this [[docs]](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types):

```
request(method: 'post'|'put')
```

But in Swift I am writing bad code like:

```
// See RFC7231 and RFC5789 for more info
enum HttpMethods: String {
    case GET = "GET"
    case HEAD = "HEAD"
    case POST = "POST"
    case PUT = "PUT"
    case DELETE = "DELETE"
    case CONNECT = "CONNECT"
    case OPTIONS = "OPTIONS"
    case TRACE = "TRACE"
    case PATCH = "PATCH"
}
```

**How do I restrict the allowed inputs of a Swift function at compile-time?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your capitalization is off for Swift. What you probably meant was:

```
enum HTTPMethod: String {
    case get = "GET"
    case head = "HEAD"
    case post = "POST"
    case put = "PUT"
    case delete = "DELETE"
    case connect = "CONNECT"
    case options = "OPTIONS"
    case trace = "TRACE"
    case patch = "PATCH"
}
```

If lowercase string constants are OK, as you've done in the Typescript, you'd probably write it this way to get the same thing. A String enum automatically is its own value.

```
enum HTTPMethods: String {
    case get, head, post, put, delete, connect, options, trace, patch
}
```

If you want to have lowercase constant names, but upper case string values, then you'd need to use the first version.

To use that to restrict a parameter, you just use the type:

```
func request(method: HTTPMethod)
```

Comment: Ah yep, that's it. Knew I was near the right track :P

Answer (score 0):

## Overview:

- Use `OptionSet` to support multiple values.

## Code:

```
struct HTTPMethod : OptionSet {

    let rawValue : Int

    static let get      = HTTPMethod(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    static let head     = HTTPMethod(rawValue: 1 << 1)
    static let post     = HTTPMethod(rawValue: 1 << 2)
    static let put      = HTTPMethod(rawValue: 1 << 3)
    static let delete   = HTTPMethod(rawValue: 1 << 4)
    static let connect  = HTTPMethod(rawValue: 1 << 5)
    static let trace    = HTTPMethod(rawValue: 1 << 6)
    static let patch    = HTTPMethod(rawValue: 1 << 7)
}

func doSomething(method: HTTPMethod) {


}

doSomething(method: [.get, .head, .put])
```

## Refer:

- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optionset